# get meta tags with php don't work

Tags: php

I want take a meta take like this

```
<meta name="twitter:player" class="twitter_player" value="https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/31306908">
```

in php , with  get_meta_tags(url) take all meta tags but meta like this who have value is null, i want take value from this meta i try and

```
$doc= new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($values['ig_create_url']);
$meta= $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
```

however it's not working , come back a object with 0 element

Comment: try to replace `$doc->loadHTMLFile($values['ig_create_url']);` with `$doc->loadHTMLFile(file_get_contents($values['ig_create_url']));`

Comment: don't want work , i try but again give a object with 0 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this ?

```
$doc= new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<meta name="twitter:player" class="twitter_player" value="https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/31306908">');
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $tag)
{
    echo $tag->getAttribute('value');
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/31306908
```

---

**`EDIT :`**

> same similar but , i want load a link to get from there all meta tags

You need to make use of `file_get_contents()` for that.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://yoururl.com');
$doc= new DOMDocument;
$doc->@loadHTML($html); //<----- Pass the above $html variable here
```

Comment: same similar but , i want load a link to get from there all meta tags

Comment: @user3270074,Check the edited answer on how to do it.

Comment: i try your sugestion and i make $doc= new DOMDocument;
  $html=  file_get_contents($values['ig_create_url']);
  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  $meta= $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
  var_dump($meta);

Comment: and result is object(DOMNodeList)#169 (0) {
}

Comment: $value['ig_create_url']=http://www.slideshare.net/damonnofar/5-tips-for-better-typography-in-your-slides-31306908 , if u load this page in browser u will see have some meta tags imposibile to be null object